# New to Data Science - What to use when looking for a pattern/relationship between items and an outcome

Tags: python, recommender-system, prediction

I am new to data science and I am hoping I can start applying it to my job. I have watched some videos on places like Udemy for Machine Learning and Python etc.

Anyway, I have a task but I am not sure what I need to look into to solve it.
I have a PCB/Circuit board which has 80 components on it. I also have a piece of test equipment that measures each component and logs the results with a reading of what was measured and then a simple 1 or 0 for the result I.E. Pass/Fail

Lately we have notice a component has started to fail a lot on the tester. One of the tasks I have been give is has any of the other components changed in their readings and could this have an effect?

So my question is, what would I use if I wanted to see if another component potentially has influence?

An example may help if my explanation is poor.

Lets says I have these components and the general readings I expect

```
Component    Reading     Outcome
C1            1.5 nf     Pass
C2            1.0 uf     Pass
C25           10 nf      Pass
R22           100 kohms  Pass 
R53           150 kohms  Pass
```

Now lets say C25 is failing because the reading has gone up.

```
Component    Reading    Outcome
C1            1.5 nf    Pass
C2            1.0 uf    Pass
C25           12 nf     Fail
R22           80 kohms  Pass
R53           150 kohms Pass
```

If you notice, R22 has dropped. 
Now say that this is the pattern. If R22 reads low then C25 can read high and potentially fail. What can I use to find this link/pattern/relationship?

Comment: try a basic decision tree.  I like rpart. http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a stepwise logistic regression with C25 pass/fail as the response and the readings of the other components as predictors.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python) here.

Statistically speaking, there may be a correlation if you see variables moving together (either towards or opposite) which can help you understand the relationship. You would want to use the Readings column here.